# WCF: how to ensure if an updated was successful?

Tags: database, wcf, entity-framework

I have a WCF service, hosted in a win form application, that receive the requests from the clients. One of this requests, is update the stock of the items.

Well, my idea is to use a client to send to the WCF service the new amount of items, then the service use Entity Framework 4.1 to update the database with the new stock.

How the service is duplex, when the services has finished the update, it sends a message to the client to notify that the operations is successful. That's if there is no problems.

However, I have a question. It's possible that the client send the command to the service to update the stock. The service receive the command correctly, but before the operation is finished, the client lost the connection with the service, so the services can't send to the client the status of the operation, so the user does not know if it's all ok or not.

My second question has the same logic, but with the WCF service. It's possible that the WCF service is installed in other computer different to the computer in which is installed the database. So it's possible that the WCF services send correctly the command to the database, but before the database notify that the operation is successful, the WCF service lost the connection, so it never receive a response from the database but the operation is successful. How can the user know if the operation is ok or not?

So my question is, in WCF, how can I be sure that critical operations are successful or not?

Thanks.
Daimroc.